# Convert array elements from string to integer

Tags: ruby

I have this string:

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

I need to turn it into an array like this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not a string.

Answer (score 5):

```
x = ["1","2","3","4"] 
x.map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`map`** or **`map!`** and [**`to_i`**](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i)

```
> a = ["1","2","3","4"]
> a.map(&:to_i)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
> a
#=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

---

```
> a.map!(&:to_i)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
> a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Note:** Difference between `map` and `map!` is `map` method will return new array while `map!` method will override original array. for more info **[Refer Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)**

Answer (score 1):

You have an array where each element is a **String** and you want to convert each element to an **Integer**.

There're some methods in Ruby that can help you with [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-map) being the handiest.

Map takes a block as an argument and run it against each element in the array and returns a new array where it's elements are the results of each transformation. So, if you would do something like:

```
["1","2","3"].map do |n|
  n.to_i
end
```

It would call the block (everything between do/end) once for **each** element, makin **n** assume the value of the element being transformed.

You could rewrite the snippet above to use curly braces instead of do/end block:

```
["1","2","3"].map { |n| n.to_i }
```

Or better yet, use Ruby's **&** operator to call #to_i directly:

```
["1","2","3"].map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Just relised I wrote the question incorrectly.

Should have been:

I have a string:

`a = "["1","2","3","4"]"`

and I want to return an array:

`a = [1,2,3,4]`

I ended up doing this:

`JSON.parse(a).map{|a| a.to_i})`

Comment: You can edit your post. But I would recommend to create a new question. But `a = "["1","2","3","4"]"` is no String, it is a syntax error. Do yo mean `a = "[1,2,3,4]"` or `a = '["1","2","3","4"]'`?